# $\dfrac{y\mathrm{e}^{yx}}{x}dy+e^{xy}dx=0$ finding integrating factor?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$\dfrac{y\mathrm{e}^{yx}}{x}dy+e^{xy}dx=0$ Find the integrating factor

ı have tried using $\frac{N_x-M_Y}{xM-yN} = R$ but could't get anything

Comment: it is fixed now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\dfrac{y\mathrm{e}^{yx}}{x}dy+e^{xy}dx=0$$
$$e^{xy}({y}dy+xdx)=0$$
$${y}dy+xdx=0$$
Integrate:
$$y^2+x^2=C$$

---

$$\dfrac{y\mathrm{e}^{yx}}{x}dy+e^{xy}dx=0$$
You can multiply by $\mu (x,y)=xe^{-xy}$ then the DE becomes exact.
$$ydy+xdx=0$$
Is exact.

Comment: https://imgur.com/biifMWX here is the question

Comment: I see  @ArmanTuran but note that $xdx+ydy=0$ is exact

Comment: Then multiply by $e^{-xy}x$ the DE then it's exact @ArmanTuran